# How to convert string to datetime and then get the lowest date

Tags: c#, linq

Records are coming from database and date is in the string format. I am using LINQ `Min()` query to select the record with lowest date. LINQ is not allowing me to use `Convert.ToDateTime()`.

How can I get lowest date record?

Comment: Please link your code.

Comment: how about changing the datatype in database as `Date` instead of `string`

Comment: And specify your date/time format. Why is your date/time data in text format in the database anyway? I'd fix that, if you possibly can.

Comment: procedure returning data is converting datetime to varchar. i get sting in format "mm/dd/yyyy"

Comment: You should be very careful about this approach. Are you absolutely sure that the date format on the DB is predictable and consistent, and not depending on temporary language settings on storing clients?

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like

```
.Min(ob => System.Convert.ToDateTime(ob.DateProperty));
```

This way the value gets converted before checking for the lowest value.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "linq is not allowing me Convert.ToDateTime()" ?

Can you not do:

```
DateTime minDate = listOfStrings.Select(x => Convert.ToDateTime(x)).Min();
```

..?

If the strings are not in a date/time format that is handled by [`Convert.ToDateTime()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xhz1w05e%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), you may need to look into [`DateTime.ParseExact()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx) with an appropriate format string.

*Edit:* sorry, just realized another possibility. Do you mean that you cannot do the `Convert.ToDateTime()` because you are using LINQ against SQL and it is not usable within the expression? If so, try:

```
DateTime minDate = listOfStrings.ToList().Select(x => Convert.ToDateTime(x)).Min();
```

.. with a `ToList()` to force it to perform the query and *then* to the conversion.

Comment: (from d in pendingLabResults select Convert.ToDateTime(d.ORDER_DATE_RESULTS)).Min().ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")

Comment: am using this. it is working but some time it don't return the min date.

Answer (score 0):

there's a way of doing it by using the Orderby method in your LINQ request,
using a Func() on the (datetime)field you wish to order by, then selecting the first element.

It's not very clean as i would use a datetime in the database, but it should work.

Comment: from all the records in the list i use Min() to get the min date.but some times it is not returning min date, so i thought that it is might b because date is in string, so it is not retuning the correct min date.

Comment: i guess this i because not all the values don't have the same date format ? or are you sure about this ?
you could try something like
Select(x => String.Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", x)).Min(),
i'm really not sure about this however

Answer (score 0):

Looking into some code samples would be useful. But this might help.

```
    var minDateTime = strings.Min(s => DateTime.Parse(s));
```